# Why does Mule application behave strangely in Linux server?

Tags: linux, tomcat, mule

I work with Mule and I have some problem.

My mainflow.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><mule xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:vm="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm"
xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:core="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:management="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/management"
version="CE-3.3.0"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm/current/mule-vm.xsd http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/management http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/management/current/mule-management.xsd">

<!-- For show MX4J -->
<management:jmx-default-config port="1098"
    registerMx4jAdapter="true">
</management:jmx-default-config>
<management:jmx-mx4j-adaptor jmxAdaptorUrl="http://localhost:9999"
    login="admin" password="admin">
</management:jmx-mx4j-adaptor>
<management:jmx-server enableStatistics="true">
    <management:connector-server
        url="service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/server" rebind="false" />
</management:jmx-server>
<management:rmi-server createRegistry="true" />

<!-- For get statistics -->
<notifications>
    <notification event="EXCEPTION" />
    <notification event="ENDPOINT-MESSAGE" />
    <notification-listener ref="endpointNotificationLogger" />
    <notification-listener ref="statesModuleExceptionNotificationListener" />
</notifications>

<spring:beans>

    <!-- For show MX4J -->
    <spring:bean id="exporter"
        class="org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter" lazy-init="false">
        <spring:property name="beans">
            <spring:map>
                <spring:entry key="bean:name=MBean1"
                    value-ref="MBean1" />
                <spring:entry key="bean:name=MBean2"
                    value-ref="MBean2" />
            </spring:map>
        </spring:property>
    </spring:bean>
    <spring:bean id="MBean1" name="MBean1"
        class="MBean1"></spring:bean>
    <spring:bean id="MBean2" name="MBean2"
        class="MBean2"></spring:bean>

    <!-- For get statistics -->
    <spring:bean name="endpointNotificationLogger"
        class="MyEndpointNotificationListener" />
    <spring:bean name="myExceptionNotificationListener"
        class="MyExceptionNotificationListener" />

    <spring:bean id="MyBean" name="MyBean"
        class="MyBean">
    </spring:bean>
</spring:beans>
<!-- <file:connector name="input" autoDelete="true" doc:name="File" />-->
<file:connector name="inputFileConnector" autoDelete="true" doc:name="File" >
    <service-overrides messageReceiver="myFileMessageReceiver"/>
</file:connector>
<flow name="UnpackHandler" doc:name="UnpackHandler">
    ...
</flow>
<flow name="XmlToCsvTransformHandler" doc:name="XmlToCsvTransformHandler">
    ...
</flow>
```

Everything works OK in Tomcat. But after that I commit changes to SVN, checkout everything, package without changes and deploy app in Tomcat my application do not work!

The latest text in logs of Tomcat for my application:

```
DEBUG 18.12.2014 15:12:08 997 - DisposableBeanAdapter.invokeCustomDestroyMethod - Invoking destroy method 'dispose' on bean with name '_muleSystemModel'
INFO 18.12.2014 15:12:08 997 - ModelLifecycleManager.fireDisposePhase - Disposing model: _muleSystemModel
```

And there are no any logs about errors... 
When application works OK, after this lines I see

```
DEBUG 18.12.2014 10:59:53 765 - MuleXmlBuilderContextListener.initialize - Mule config file(s): WEB-INF/classes/mainflow.xml
```

If I have this error and delete from mainflow.xml parts for `mx4j` and `notifications` everything works again:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><mule xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" mlns:vm="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm" xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:core="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="CE-3.3.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/vm/current/mule-vm.xsd http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd ">
</spring:beans>
<file:connector name="input" autoDelete="true" doc:name="File" />
<flow name="UnpackHandler" doc:name="UnpackHandler">
    ...
</flow>
<flow name="XmlToCsvTransformHandler" doc:name="XmlToCsvTransformHandler">
    ...
</flow>
```

After I write parts for `mx4j` and `notifications` step by step, do not paste all text of file what I take from SVN, it works again! So there is no difference between mainflow.xml when application works and doesn't work.

This behavior is in Linux server. In the Windows server and in my local machine everything is OK. I thought about differences between slashes, but I don't write slashes...

Why application behaves so strangely?

Comment: What is this: "this error"?

Comment: I do some changes in my mainflow.xml, then delete all changes or just copy text from previous working file instead of current file. But application does not work in Linux (See logs the above). Why does not it work with the same file in Linux although It works OK in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

With the information you provide I can only guess that you have some logic in the notifications that hangs them if something on which they are dependedant is not already initializated somehow.

The fact that later it does work would somehow indicate this. I can suggest you to use in the beans the attribute depends-on to make sure it's initialized after your bean dependencies in case there are.